# Why COALESCE, NULLIF and CAST are used?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please let me know why the following line is used in the query?

```
SELECT user_id 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST(user_id AS VARCHAR(10)) ,'0'), '')
FROM users
```

`user_id` is of type int. But if I run the following, it shows the same output as above.

```
SELECT user_id FROM users
```

Comment: Seems you need a comma after `user_id` in the first query, and you have repeated `from` in the second.

Comment: And from your understanding and research of those functions, what do you think it does?

Comment: Yeah, there are other columns in the table as well

Comment: Not sure how the presence of other columns is relevant? You're still missing a comma...

Comment: You could create yourself a [quick test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13bf3a959bc69f87b29fccb6d7a2b820) to explain what this query does.

Comment: @DaleK cast changes the type of uer_id from int to varchar. Nullif compares the user_id type with 0, if they are equal, it returns null, otherwise it returns the user_id type. Coalesce returns the first non null value.

Comment: So there you have it :) what more can we tell you?

Comment: Am I wrong or couldn't it be reduced to   concat(nullif(user_id,0),'')

Comment: NullIf seems still superfluous COALESCE(CAST(user_id AS VARCHAR(10)), '') gives the same result

Comment: @nbk I'm guessing 0's should be treated as null   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=420af083b4a23c183214600d729a7f11

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Coalesce can do the same https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6c4288fbd7635fb05067b5ebce611788 i am unsure what is faster, but  i am guessing COALESCE

Comment: @nbk I think you got it flipped in your head.   0 and null should be an empty string

Comment: The whole point here is to display a blank value rather a zero. Nobody seems to be saying that succintly.

Comment: @shawnt00 I guess everyone thought that was too obvious for that to be the question OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Let's check it out by parts:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST(user_id AS VARCHAR(10)) ,'0'), '')
```

**COALESCE** is a method useful when you want ensure some value instead `NULL`
imagine some query and a specific column will be used to a math operation, you will prefer receive `0` instead of NULL. So **COALESCE(USE THIS VALUE IF IS NOT NULL, OR USE THIS)**

**NULLIF** check two arguments, and return null in the case they have same value, otherwise return value of first argument

**CAST** is a method to transform the type of something into other type, such the integer 1 into string "1", remember 1 is not equal to "1"

so

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST(user_id AS VARCHAR(10)) ,'0'), '')
```

means, if the converted to string value of user_id is '0', I want this to evaluate to '', otherwise return it transformed into a string value.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the answer to "why it's used" is "it doesn't have to be used", because there's a way to express it that's easier to understand and performs better.

Your observation that the output is the same is incorrect: It *looks* the same, but it *isn't* the same because `user_id` is an `integer` in the table and the simple query out, but `varchar(10)` in the complicated query output.

This produces equivalent output:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN user_id = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE CAST(user_id AS VARCHAR(10))
  END AS user_id
FROM users
```

And needs no explanation to understand.